# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i have been struggling with the compilation of an app. this a demo app which I downloaded from internet for learning purpose. but I receive `ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'`. like shown in the image below. [image]

I have checked dozens of forums and applied many gradle verions, old and new. but nothing worked.

Here is the project: gradle code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my app: gradle code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
buildscript {
   repositories {
      maven {url 'https://maven.google.com' }
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
   }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `implementation` method inside the `buildscript` block:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       maven {url 'https://maven.google.com' }
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1' remove it
    }
}

//Add this block
dependencies {
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
}
```